# Windows Subsystem for Linux, runs Linux apps on Windows startup?

Tags: linux, windows, debian, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently installed Debian from the Windows store and installed a package I would like to run when Windows starts. Is this possible? I have tried creating a batch file in the Startup folder that starts Debian through the command prompt, but it won't then run the following commands once Linux has started.

Comment: Yes, I can think of many ways to do this.  What "following commands"?  That would help me pick one for you.

Comment: The commands are:

"export DISPLAY=:0"
and
"tzclock"

So I want it to run tzclock on Windows startup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably 100 ways to do this.. this is what I would do.

***The problems that we will need to solve are***

1. The x-server needs to launch without prompting. I am using VcXsrv.  I had to make a "config.xlaunch" configuration file so it would start up without prompting me.  If you launch VcXsrv and get the prompts, saving that config is on the last screen.
2. The x-server will need to launch and be running before the command to launch an x11-app fires up.
3. We will want to hide the bash window that is hosting the command so you don't have a stupid console window hanging around.

For my sample, I will be starting the ***world famous*** *xeyes* app from a super simple PowerShell script.  I chose PowerShell because it makes it simple to hide a window.
We will use the sleep command to wait for the x-server to start.  You would never want to do this (sleep) with REAL code.. but who cares here? right?

Create a powershell script *somewhere*.. your documents folder is a good place but what do I care?

Put these three lines in it (modify for what you want)..

```
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\\Program Files\\VcXsrv\\xlaunch.exe" -ArgumentList "-run `"C:\\Users\\CMasMas\\Documents\\config.xlaunch`""
Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
Start-Process -WindowStyle hidden -FilePath "C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe" -ArgumentList "-c 'DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0 /usr/bin/xeyes'"`
```

Try running the "powershell.exe [path_to_your].PS1" command from the prompt.
If you get the error:  `cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system` then you will need to use the `Set-ExecutionPolicy` scriptlet to allow scripts to be run on your system.  This involves security settings and I am not prepared to tell you all of the caveats.  Go to the URL provided with the error.  It will explain your options.

Now, create a shortcut to powershell.exe and add the path to the PS1 file after powershell.exe.  Put this shortcut in your startup group.

Please let me know if I can help further.